# Nextjs : why the browser tab freezes when I use router.push()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, router

```json
"next": "12.3.0",
```

To be more precise this does not happen all the time, let's say in 85% it works fine but sometimes the browser tap freezes and I can't click on anything, all I can do is to close it.

No errors in the browser console neither in the terminal and the app works fine.

I have a button that calls an API and after reciving the data I want to  `router.push()` to the same page. and as I montioned it is not happening all the time so it should not be a problem with my code.

```js
<Button                                      
onClick={async() => {              
 await axios
   .patch('url', updateTrackDto)
   .then((res) => { 
       router.push(`/tracks`); // this is the path of the same page
  }).catch((error) => {
       console.log(error);
  });
}>update</Button>
```

**getServerSideProps :**

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const trackId = context.params.trackId;
  const track = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/track/get/${trackId}`);
  return {
    props: {
      track: track.data,
    },
  };
}
```

I checked, there are no infinite renders or infinite loops or anything not working as expected, the stricMode is enabled. Can it be a problem with `getServerSideProps()` getting called many times ? because when I keep clicking on the button this is happening on the 8-9th click/getServerSideProps call

Comment: why do you want to refresh the page

Comment: why not call the get method inside the component rather than refreshing the entire page

Comment: if you want to refresh, try using router.reload instead https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerreload

Comment: btw, you do not need to refresh page to update the data

Comment: getServerSideProps is used for the first render, not to get updated data. Why do not you make an api call instead? using router.push to the same route does not make sense to me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*the app freezes*"? I dropped a comment on a question that I think is similar to yours explaining some things about `getServerSideProps`. You can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74649874/page-freezes-for-1-or-2-seconds-each-time-it-renders-nextjs), maybe this is also your case.